# In the phase flip action on standard basis, why do we consider the $-1$ phase only for the $|1\rangle$?

Tags: pauli-gates, bloch-sphere

Prof. Watrous in the first lecture of Qiskit summer school 2023, mentions:

> "....the significance of putting a minus sign in front of the $|1\rangle$
> basis vector and not $|0\rangle$ will be more clear later"

when he is describing the action of the phase flip operator on the standard basis.

I am now, halfway through his video lectures, and I have not yet come across the answer to this question! As I understand, the action is like the action of the rotation matrix (on the Bloch sphere), and rotation matrices induce global phases for both $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$!

Why do we decide to consider the $-1$ phase only for the $|1\rangle$ and ignore that for $|0\rangle$?

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is a global phase when considering just the basis vector $|1\rangle$, it will not be a global phase for some arbitrary superposition and will have some physical significance.

$$Z \big( \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle \big) = \alpha |0\rangle - \beta |1\rangle\,.$$

This ability to induce a phase difference is useful in implementing quantum algorithms where we use interference to cancel out states in the superposition which are not the *"answer"* we are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. Can you also clarify why only the 1 ket gets the phase and not the zero ket? Is that some kind of convention? Because with the rotation matrix, they both get a phase!

Comment: It is just how we define the phase flip operation, Pauli $Z$. $$Z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \,.$$ So, $$Z|0\rangle = |0\rangle\,,$$ $$Z|1\rangle = -|1\rangle\,.$$ You can consider operator $-Z$ $$-Z = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \,.$$ So, $$Z|0\rangle = -|0\rangle\,,$$ $$Z|1\rangle = |1\rangle\,.$$